# DrawerLayout image with certain phones

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'm using a `DrawerLayout` with an image in the background behind my `ListView`. The `ListView` has transparent background to see the image under neath it, this works on all phones I tested (nexus, htc, etc.) except for the Samsung Galaxy S line. For some reason, on a Galaxy S phone, it's not showing the `ImageView` underneath. It's just showing the transparent black background. However, I see no errors in my log files in the process. Is there anything i'm missing in my code? Why is the Samsung device not showing it properly?

I have my xml layout below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_layout"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/left_navigation_bar" />

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#99000000"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `list_image` View is what is missing on my Galaxy s phone (I tried on 3, 4, and 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the galaxy phone wasn't able to handle such a big image. I had to shrink the sizes of my images to make this work.

Comment: I'm not able to. I have to wait 48 hours.